# Jackson polymorphic serialization issue. EXTERNAL_PROPERTY type info is ignored.

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I've got some problems with jackson serialization.

I just want to add field with type of property value.

Seems that PackageInfo annotation is just ignored.

```
package somepackage.settings.dto;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

import java.util.Date;

public class SettingsItemRequest {

    private String key;

    @JsonTypeInfo(
            use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
            include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
            property = "type",
            visible = true
    )
    @JsonSubTypes(
            value = {
                    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = String.class, name = "string"),
                    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Number.class, name = "number"),
                    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Boolean.class, name = "boolean"),
                    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Date.class, name = "date")
            }
    )
    private Object value;

    private String type;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Whatever I do, result stays the same, property type is null(or missing, if I remove property `type`) in result json.

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In a similar use case, I implemented it as following. The child classes were setting the type property in the constructors.
Also from separation of concerns perspective, if there is a child class per dedicated type, then each class can just set the type in the constructor.